# JAXB Validator does not detect syntax errors?

Tags: java, xml, validation, jaxb

I want to validate a xml file with its xsd before unmarshalling it.

The code is as follows :

```
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(xsdFilePath);
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.setErrorHandler(new MyValidationErrorHandler());
validator.validate(new StreamSource(xmlFilePath));
```

I found that when a xml element is not closed, Validator failed to record it as an error, But the UnMarshaller recognizes this and throws an "Invalid content was found starting with element.." Error.

I want the Validation and the Unmarshalling/Marshalling to be different operations.

Are there ways to have the Validator detect such syntax errors in the xml file?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to distinguish two things:

1. The elementary syntax of an XML document
2. The document's compliance with an XML SChema

If the elementary syntax isn't right, there's no document that can be investigated for its element structure, attribure existence, value compliance with facets and so on and so on.

I'm afraid you'll have to catch both kinds of exceptions.

You may, however, handle everything in a single unmarshalling operation:

```
JAXBContext payloadContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("generated");
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = payloadContext.createUnmarshaller();
unmarshaller.setSchema(schemaFactory.newSchema(... )););
unmarshaller.setEventHandler( new ValidationEventHandler(){
    public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
            System.out.println( "Event! " + event );
            return true;
    }
} );
```

**Later**

To have validation only, you'll still have to parse, but if you don't have JAXB-ish classes, you get by with JAXP:

```
static class Handler implements ErrorHandler {
  public void error(SAXParseException exception){
    System.out.println( "error: " + exception.getMessage() );
  }
  public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception){
    System.out.println( "fatal: " + exception.getMessage() );
  }
  public void warning(SAXParseException exception){
    System.out.println( "warning: " + exception.getMessage() );
  }
}

Handler handler = new Handler();
DocumentBuilder parser = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
parser.setErrorHandler( handler );
try {
    Document document = parser.parse(new File("test.xml"));
    SchemaFactory factory =
      SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(new File("test.xsd"));
    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    validator.setErrorHandler( handler );
    try {
      validator.validate(new DOMSource(document));
    } catch (SAXException e) {
      // ...
      System.out.println( "VAlidation error" );
    }
} catch (SAXParseException e) {
    // syntax error in XML document     
    System.out.println( "Syntax error" );
}
```

For validation, setting a handler will not throw a ParseException, so one of these is redundant.

Comment: The reason why I want to keep validation and unmarshalling separately is because I want the validation to be as generic as possible, without much dependency on JAXBContext as this is going to be reused in several places for validating xml files. I want to have a validation API that would report both the syntax/parse errors in the xml file as well as its Schema compliance errors.